# IRC channel about game development?

Tags: game-mechanics

I'm looking for some IRC channel to talk about game development.

Anyone know some?

Comment: IRC? Nonsense: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development

Comment: It would be better, if you have game development-related questions, to just ask those questions here.  This question doesn't really fit within the scope of the site as defined in the faq.  That being said, we do have a [web-based chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development) here on the site.

Answer (score 3):

#ludumdare on irc.afternet.org, Other than that I suggest searching for channels about frameworks you are interested in.